# Hover state in table with border shifting link only in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I know this type of question has been asked in some way shape or form on here but i cannot get this to work no matter what. Screenshot included as well the CSS. When you hover on the row, the left border highlights it. It's moving the link over 1px. I tried compensating with negative margin but no luck ( just to test it). It's only Firefox where this is happening.

[image]

```
%zebra-row {
   transition: background-color .1s ease-out;
   background-clip:padding-box;

  &:nth-child(odd ) {
    background-color: $alabaster;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: $gallery;
    border-left:2px solid $aqua-forest;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the border is being applied and moving it over (as I'm sure you've assumed).

To get around this, you'll want to have a default border present but make it transparent. On the hover, you'll simply color the border.

```
%zebra-row {
   transition: background-color .1s ease-out;
   background-clip:padding-box;
   border-left:2px solid transparent;    /* Set the transparent border */

  &:nth-child(odd ) {
    background-color: $alabaster;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: $gallery;
    border-left-color:$aqua-forest;      /* Color it on hover */
  }
}
```

This prevents the "jump" you were talking about because the border is, essentially, always there.

Comment: thanks! the only thing is that this code gets rid of the border on the left (it is gray by default ( check the screengrab)

Comment: @erics15 You can also play with padding to get the same result. Perhaps add `1px` padding, then remove it on hover. Your precompiled CSS and lack of a working example make it a little difficult to provide a 100% accurate code sample. This should lead you in the right direction, however.